# Duplicate Management with Auto Merge

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, duplicate-management, sales-cloud

In Sales Cloud, we would like to auto merge a lead to a contact being entered by a user if there is a match on email (contact to lead).

I tried using duplicate rules and there is in fact an error that is thrown or an alert but not sure how to perform the auto-merge of the lead to the contact.

Any insights ?

Comment: There is no standard feature automerge, you'd have to build it yourself or get a dedupe app that has that feature. Something like Cloudingo, DemandTools, ect.

Comment: Is there any sample code available for this ? If we can detect an event when a duplicate rule is enforced then we can handle via Apex or Flow the rest.

Comment: Not that I know of, we bought the app to solve the problem.